# the difference of a default constructor & nonparametric constructor in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I found one interesting thing in java while making some programs. Here is one simple code.
When I made this code, class Son occured an error. It means 2nd constructor needs a nonparametric constructor like this one.. public classname(){} .

But, all classes have their own default constructor so I don't think there's no need to make nonparametric constructor. Is there a difference between them?

```
class Papa 
{
    private int papa_var;

    public Papa(String name, int age)
    {
    }
}

class Son extends Papa
{
    private int son_var;

    public Son(String name, int age)
    {
        super(name,age);
    }
    public Son(int car, int robot)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**But, all classes have their own default constructor so I don't think there's no need to make nonparametric constructor. Is there a difference between them?** - No. Java provides a *default* or *non-parameterized* constructor only if you define no other constructor

Answer (score 2):

Java implicitly provides a default constructor only if you have not provided one explicitly. It is the duty of the constructor of the subclass to call the constructor of the super class. Therefore you have to explicitly add a statement in the subclass constructor using super keyword to call the super class constructor. That is the error in your second constructor of class Son.

Had there been no constructor provided by you in both the class the implicit default constructor of the class Son would have also called the constructor of class Papa at the time of initialization of the objects of class Son.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor (`public MyClass() {}`) is only implicitly created if your class doesn't have another constructor defined.
If it does, you must explicitly define a no-args constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is that, in the absence of a default constructor (without parameters), you're compelled to call a superconstructor in the lines of:

```
public Son(int car, int robot)
{
    super("papa_name", 99);
}
```

**If you declare a constructor (whatever form and signature it may have)**, your *default* (non-parametric) constructor is ***not*** created by the compiler and therefore the `super` call I wrote above cannot be deduced (the compiler may not know which superconstructor you want to call, even if you wrote just one - you may add however many later). As such, the compiler plays it safe and you're getting an error.

If you *had* written a constructor without arguments or had one by default (i.e. wrote no constructors yourself), then the compiler would have deduced a super call as in

```
public Son(int car, int robot)
{
    super();
}
```

even though you didn't have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the *default* constructor is a constructor without parameters (i.e. non-parametric) because if you don't have *any* constructor it is created *by default* behind the scenes. The same is true for calls to constructors of super classes, i.e. if there is no explicit call to a super constructor (or a "this"-constructor) Java will insert a call to the no-argument super constructor *by default* (i.e. `super();` is added implicitly).

In your case there are explicit constructors so Java won't automatically create a default constructor and since there isn't one for `Papa` the implicit `super();` in `Son(int car, int robot)` won't succeed - hence the error.